# Move moodle to production server

Tags: apache, virtualhost, moodle

I'm in the process of moving my moodle installation to the production server (Centos 7.5), at this moment there is only one more site on the server -a wordpress one- that has his domain name. This new site don't have a domain name yet, I just need it to be available for review.

When I try to enter directly to IP adress https://xxx.xxx.xx.239/moodle I get the not found page of the wordpress installation.

Now, what I did so far, it's:

- Upload the folder containing the moodle installation in the same directory that contains the wordpress folder (var/www/html).
- Import the database
- **Try** to configure the virtualhost on the etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf file.
- **Try** to edit the main config.php file of moodle accordingly.

This are my files:

## cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.name.mx/httpdocs
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.name.mx
    #Source code
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site.name.mx/httpdocs
    ## Logs
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/site.name.mx/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/site.name.mx/logs/access_log combined

    ##Redireccionar a https 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName moodle.site.mx
    ##Source code
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle.site.mx
    ## Logs
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/moodle.site.mx/logs/error_log
    CustomLog /var/www/html/moodle.site.mx/logs/access_log combined
  </VirtualHost>
```

## cat /var/www/html/moodle.srsweb.mx/config.php

```
<?php  // Moodle configuration file

unset($CFG);
global $CFG;
$CFG = new stdClass();

$CFG->dbtype    = 'mysqli';
$CFG->dblibrary = 'native';
$CFG->dbhost    = 'localhost';
$CFG->dbname    = 'moodle';
$CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'n0770b3s33nh3r3';
$CFG->prefix    = 'mdl_';
$CFG->dboptions = array (
'dbpersist' => 0,
'dbport' => 3307,
'dbsocket' => '',
'dbcollation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
);

$CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://XXX.XXX.XX.239/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = '/home/centos/moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

$CFG->directorypermissions = 0777;

require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');

// There is no php closing tag in this file,
// it is intentional because it prevents trailing whitespace problems!
```

**What I'm doing wrong? What should I do in order to make this new site accesible? (using the server IP)**

Answer (score 0):

Your second Apache virtual host is the one pointing to Moodle, but because both virtual hosts share the same IP, you are using name-based virtual hosts.  Therefore, you will not be able to access it directly by IP address.  Apache needs a `Host: moodle.site.mx` header included in your browser's request to know to send it to the proper virtual host.

Instead it is looking for a /moodle subfolder on your default virtual host, which assumedly does not exist.

Two options for solving it:

1. Setup the DNS name you want to reach Moodle with and use that in your browser.  If that is not yet possible, you can do a temporary workaround of changing your local HOSTS file to have an entry for (and use the DNS name in your browser):

   > XXX.XXX.XX.239   moodle.site.mx
2. Modify Apache to listen on either two IP addresses or two ports (80 and 8080, for example), so you can make a request to that specific virtual host.